# How to set up a Site-to-Site VPN tunnel with xfrm

Tags: vpn

I am trying for a few days to create a VPN tunnel between 2 sites, but with no success.

## Scenario

I have the following scenario:

- Site A with the 192.168.1.0/24 IP addresses and a gateway GWA with the addresses 192.168.1.254 and a.b.c.d (Internet facing).
- Site B with the 192.168.2.0/24 IP addresses and a gateway GWB with the addresses 192.168.2.254 and e.f.g.h(Internet facing).

## XFRM Policies and States

I managed to add the states and policies for each gateway correctly (I think).

For GWA I used the following commands:

```
# policies in, out, fwd
ip xfrm policy add src 192.168.1.0/24 dst 192.168.2.0/24 dir out tmpl src a.b.c.d dst e.f.g.h proto esp reqid 0x99 mode tunnel
ip xfrm policy add src 192.168.2.0/24 dst 192.168.1.0/24 dir in tmpl src e.f.g.h dst a.b.c.d proto esp reqid 0x99 mode tunnel 
ip xfrm policy add src 192.168.2.0/24 dst 192.168.1.0/24 dir fwd tmpl src e.f.g.h dst a.b.c.d proto esp reqid 0x99 mode tunnel<br> 
# states
ip xfrm state add src a.b.c.d dst e.f.g.h proto esp spi 0x81 reqid 0x99 mode tunnel auth "hmac(sha256)" 0x01 enc "rfc3686(ctr(aes))" 0x02
ip xfrm state add src e.f.g.h dst a.b.c.d proto esp spi 0x82 reqid 0x99 mode tunnel auth "hmac(sha256)" 0x03 enc "rfc3686(ctr(aes))" 0x04
```

For GWB I used the following commands:

```
# policies in, out, fwd
ip xfrm policy add src 192.168.2.0/24 dst 192.168.1.0/24 dir out tmpl src e.f.g.h dst a.b.c.d proto esp reqid 0x99 mode tunnel
ip xfrm policy add src 192.168.1.0/24 dst 192.168.2.0/24 dir in tmpl src a.b.c.d dst e.f.g.h proto esp reqid 0x99 mode tunnel 
ip xfrm policy add src 192.168.1.0/24 dst 192.168.2.0/24 dir fwd tmpl src a.b.c.d dst e.f.g.h proto esp reqid 0x99 mode tunnel<br>
# states
ip xfrm state add src a.b.c.d dst e.f.g.h proto esp spi 0x81 reqid 0x99 mode tunnel auth "hmac(sha256)" 0x01 enc "rfc3686(ctr(aes))" 0x02
ip xfrm state add src e.f.g.h dst a.b.c.d proto esp spi 0x82 reqid 0x99 mode tunnel auth "hmac(sha256)" 0x03 enc "rfc3686(ctr(aes))" 0x04
```

## Routes

Each host from Site A knows to route packets destined for Site B via GWA.

Each host from Site B know to route packets destined for Site A via GWB.

## Results

A packet sent from a host in Site A to a host in Site B arrives at GWA and is encrpyted (as a ESP packet). The ESP packet arrives at GWB and it's successfully decrypted, but it get's dropped.

## What did I miss?

Do I need virtual/tunnel interfaces? (vti, tun, tap) 
Do I need to add entries in iptables?
Are my xfrm commands correct?

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. My approach was correct, but because of a kernel bug (in many 5.2.x versions and also some 4.x versions) the ip xfrm tool didn't work properly.

A workaround was using strongswan/swanctl with their own IPSec implementation. For more see this: [kernel-libsec plugin](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Kernel-libipsec).
You will need to build and compile it yourself.